# How to set infinity focus in camera2 api, android?

Tags: android, android-camera2

I wanna set my custom camera focus distance to infinity while using external fisheye lens, This is what I have done so far:

```
builder.set(CaptureRequest.CONTROL_AF_MODE, CaptureRequest.CONTROL_AF_MODE_OFF);
builder.set(CaptureRequest.LENS_FOCUS_DISTANCE, 0.0f);
```

But the result is so blurry.

I am using Samsung S6 and Nexus 5.
External lens's wide angle is 170 degree.

Can anyone help?

Comment: have you tried modifying the FOCUS_RANGE?

Comment: No, I have not. I will try

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are just talking about using the built-in camera's lens to achieve fisheye, then the lowest value you should use is:

```
float minFocalDist = cameraCharacteristics.get(CameraCharacteristics.LENS_INFO_MINIMUM_FOCUS_DISTANCE);
```

If you are using an external lens, then I believe that the correct approach is actually to use autofocus on the camera, since that should focus to the focal length of the fish eye lens... I think. So the external lens is taking care of fisheye and the internal is taking care of autofocus. However, if this doesn't work, then see what you get when you set the focal length to the hyperfocal distance. That distance might not be optimal, but it should work in most cases...

```
float hyperFocalDist = cameraCharacteristics.get(CameraCharacteristics.LENS_INFO_HYPERFOCAL_DISTANCE);
```

Comment: I have just tried hyberfocal distance. it returns `0.2` and the result is almost same as `0.0`

Comment: This seems to be an alignment issue then. The hyperfocal length should almost always work. It could be that the axis of the external lens is not perfectly aligned with the camera axis. This needs to be very precise, and if you just kind of eyeball the connection, you could get bad results. Is there a dedicated adapter that you have to attach the lens to the phone?

Comment: It is a phone case and lens is attached in right place

Comment: Well, in this case, you know that the focal distance of the camera must be in the range [0.0f, android.lens.info.minimumFocusDistance]. You should try several values in this range to get a feel for which distance is the best. It could turn out that the camera needs to have a focal distance outside of the supported range to bring the fisheye into focus (this would be really bad). You would essentially figure that out by determining that the best focal distance occurs at either 0 or android.lens.info.minimumFocusDistance.

Comment: Did you just end up manually tuning the value?  Or what was the issue...

Comment: I just let users to select one of those options: infinity focus and autofocus. By default it is infinity, the focus distance is set to Hyper Focal Distance. If they touch screen `CONTROL_AF_MODE` turns to `AUTO` and camera tries to find focus. but it fails mostly

Comment: It would be great If you help for this issue too http://stackoverflow.com/q/42090124/5344661

Comment: Sorry, but I have no idea on the other issue. I have never had a problem with autofocus. Actually, I usually use hyperfocal in my work.

Answer (score 2):

For anyone googling here, to get
Android CameraX, camera characteristics such as CameraCharacteristics.LENS_INFO_MINIMUM_FOCUS_DISTANCE.

For 2021 the syntax is like ...

So, you've gone through the process of getting the camera ...

```
theCamera = cameraProvider.bindToLifecycle((LifecycleOwner)this,
              yourCameraSelector, yourImageAnalysis, yourPreview);
```

the code nowadays is:

```
CameraCharacteristics camChars = Camera2CameraInfo
   .extractCameraCharacteristics(theCamera.getCameraInfo());
float discoveredMinFocusDistance = camChars
   .get(CameraCharacteristics.LENS_INFO_MINIMUM_FOCUS_DISTANCE);
```