# Searching focus keeps failing with external lens, camera2 api in android

Tags: android, autofocus, android-camera2

I am using camera2 api for my custom camera. I implemented touch to focus. It is working fine. But when I'm trying to attach external lens, it can't find focus distance, I have to try several times. Native camera works perfectly even with the lens. What else should I consider? Any opinions? please guide.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(For the further usage) I ended up the solution using [samsung camera sdk](http://developer.samsung.com/galaxy/camera). It is working perfectly